# Solving Diophantine equation without brute force

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am having trouble trying to solve this Diophantine equations:
$$
^3=4^2+4−3
$$

I was wondering if anyone could help me find the integer solutions to these and any advice of techniques to use?

Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was trying to get it in terms of a number=(...)(...), I got x^3-4=(2y+1)^2 but not sure where to go

Comment: $x^3-4=(2y+1)^2=4y^2+4y+1$ is not the same as $x^3=4y^2+4y-3$.

Comment: Meant plus 4 sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right hand side can be factored as
$$x^3=4y^2+4y-3=(2y+1)^2-4=(2y+3)(2y-1).$$
The gcd of the two factors on the right hand side divides their difference, which is $4$, but they are both odd so they are coprime. It follows from unique factorization that both factors are perfect cubes. But no two perfect cubes differ by $4$, a contradiction. Hence no integral solutions exist.

Comment: Then could I say either: x=2y+3 and x^2=2y-1 OR x=2y-1 and x^2=2y+3 ?

Comment: $2y+3-(2y-1)=4$ so you can not assume 2y-1 and 2y+3 are coprime.

Comment: how would i finish this off?

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: How did you do the cases for m=1,2?

Answer (score 1):

The equation in equivalent to 
$$
x^3+4=(2Y+1)^2=y^2,
$$
which is Mordell's equation. This has been solved here:

[Solution to Mordell's Equation $y^2=x^3+4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871646/solution-to-mordells-equation-y2-x34)

We see that $2Y+1=\pm 2$ is impossible, hence there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way**:  You can rewrite the equation: 
$$x^3+8=4y^2+4y+5$$

Or $$(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)=4y^2+4y+5$$

Let $(x+2;x^2-2x+4)=d (d\in N^+)$

Note that : $x^2-2x+4=x(x+2)-4(x+2)+12\Rightarrow d\mid 12$

We will prove $4y^2+4y+5\not\mid12$. Assume $4y^2+4y+5\mid12$, then we have $4y^2+4y+5=12k(k\in Z)$

$\Leftrightarrow (2y+1)^2=12k-4=4(3k-1)$

But $(2y+1)^2\equiv0;1\pmod{3}$ and $4(3k-1)\equiv2\pmod{3}$

Can you continue?

Comment: Not sure, quiet new to this, could u explain?

Comment: @Jamesodare: where do you feel confused?

Comment: Your exposition could use a few more words and some more commonly accepted notation to be more comprehensible. I have never seen $\vdots$ to mean divisibility; the standard symbol is $\mid$ which is `\mid`.

Comment: Sorry about that i'm bad at $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @Servaes : Thank you for the inspiring advice. ;) (+1)

Comment: Oh so contradiction, so 4y^2+4y+5 (not |)12, so there are no int solutions?

Comment: Yes, 4y^2+4y+5 (not |)12 but $(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)|12 $ so there are no integer roots.